# VoiceOver only speaks two cell and skips remainder cells

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, voiceover

My app has a banner that is made with horizontal UICollectionView.

And the data of banner get from server.

The banner has two or more count (test count was 4.).

But the VoiceOver only speaks two cell and skips remainder cells.

View Hierarchy is

ViewController > TableView > CollectionView

CollectionView in TableViewCell

```swift
- (void)setVoiceOver
{
    self.isAccessibilityElement = NO;
    self.collectionView.isAccessibilityElement = NO;
}
```

CollectionViewCell

```swift
-(void)setArr:(NSDictionary *)arr
{
    _arr = arr;

    [self setVoiceOver];
}

-(void)setVoiceOver
{
    self.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    self.contentView.accessibilityElementsHidden = NO;
    self.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat: "ad%d", _arr["bannerId"]];
}
```

I want to make VoiceOver reads all banner cells.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the VoiceOver can access the collectionViewCell which is appeared in the screen.

I tested several apps, the cells that I can access with the voiceover swipe gesuture are over the screen a little bit.

like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZcbv.png)

So the voiceover have to adjust to collectionview, not the collectionviewcell.

And we can access each cell by scrolling gesture (three finger swipe)